# I need to sort objects data alphabetically

Tags: php, mysql

I have a class Shoes that consists of id, brand, price, size.
Also, I already have an sql database from which I get the data for the shoes.

I create a view class Shoes that has 6 columns. 4 aformentioned and 2 extra one with available amount of the shoe left, and one with button "buy".

I would like to have the table in the view_shoes show the shoes in an alphabetical order of the brand. So that I would have

```
1.Adidas 
2.Geox 
3.Puma 
4.Reebok.
```

Rather than

```
1.Reebok 
2.Puma 
3.Adidas 
4. Geox
```

I couldn't find much information on how to do it. I found functions like `usort`, `asort` but I can't figure out how to implement them.

Here is the function for the shoes.

```
public static function shoes() {
    $query = self::execute("SELECT * FROM shoes", array());
    $data = $query->fetchAll();
    $shoes = [];
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $shoes[] = new shoe($row['id'], $row["brand"], $row["price"], $row["size"]);
    }
    return $shoes;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ORDER BY` in your query, on the `brand` column.

```
$query = self::execute("SELECT * 
                         FROM shoes 
                         ORDER BY brand ASC"
                       , array());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either modify your SQL query to apply to sort

```
SELECT * FROM shoes
```

Replace it with

```
SELECT * FROM shoes ORDER BY brand ASC
```

OR you can use `sort()` function on `$shoes` if `$shoes` is an array

```
sort($shoes);
```

Comment: `$shoes` will be an array of objects.  You need to sort on the `brand` property of that object.

Answer (score 0):

Write your custom comparator for sorting.

```
usort($shoes,function ($a,$b){
    return strcmp($a->brand,$b->brand);
    //return strcmp($a['brand'],$b['brand']);
})
```

Comment: Each element in `$shoes` will be an object of the class `shoe`, not necessarily that you can use array-comparisons on it. You might have to fetch the brand property from the object.